# remove format button is dissapeard (CKEditor5)

Tags: bootstrap-4, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using `Bootstrap-4` with the `CKEditor5`. I have got a project where I used the Framwork above a textarea - now I came back to it and saw that the `REMOVE FORMAT - button` is disappeared.

I was looking on the homepage of `CKEditor5` (URL: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/remove-format.html) and saw that the `remove format - button` is still there but not in my project as you can see below:

On Website:
[image]

In my project:
[image]

How can I fix this problem?

*Additional Info:* I'm loading it like following in my project:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/25.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
  ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#id'))
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have taken the classic editor with it's defaults from the demo there is no "remove-format" ..
If you see the demo of that there is no such icon.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/classic-editor.html

You'll have to do a custom build and include that addon, or if it's part of the default build, add it to your toolbar through customization.

In the online builder here: https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ "Remove format" is not part of the standard build, so add it and it will show up in your toolbar.

Comment: But as you can see, based on my link, it's available in ```CKE5```.. is there a possibility that you can show how to do it? Thanks in advance and for your current repsones :)

Comment: @patrick96 yes, edited my comment with suggestion to custom build the classic editor. You have to add that addon, it's not part of the default classic build.

Comment: @patrick96 you linked to a specific feature demo. But the build you link to in your code, is a different and less featured editor, the classic one.